# Data in the text field is set to null when I scroll the table view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

Hii everyone!

I have some text fields in each cell of the table view, like this

[image]

If I enter some data into the text field and scroll the view up and down again, the data in the text field is set to null. Why does this happen, how can I avoid this?

Following is my code for cell construction

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

CustomCellStudentData *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    //  cell = [[[CustomCellStudentData alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    cell = [[[CustomCellStudentData alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:nil] autorelease];
}
[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

switch(indexPath.section)
{
    case 0:
        switch (indexPath.row) 
        {
            case 0:
            {
                tfText[0] = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(125,15, 170, 40)];
                cell.accessoryView = tfText[0];
                tfText[0].delegate = self;
                tfText[0].text = @"";
                tfText[0].placeholder = @"<Student Name>";

                cell.primaryLabel.text = @"Student Name: ";
            } 
                break;
            case 1: 
            {
                tfText[1] = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(125,15, 170, 40)];
                cell.accessoryView = tfText[1];
                tfText[1].delegate=self;
                tfText[1].placeholder = @"<Student Age>";

                cell.primaryLabel.text = @"Student Age: ";
            } 
                break;
        }
```

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when the cell is scrolled out of window, it may be released, so you must save the input in somewhere and read from there in cell construction method.

Take one cell with one textfield as example:
first I declare a NSString in my interface,and apply to UITextFieldDelegate protocol:

```
@interface someInterface : UITableViewController
<UITextFieldDelegate>
{
    NSString* contentOfTextField;
}
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString* contentOfTextField;
@end
```

then, in cellForRowAtIndex:

```
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    CustomCellStudentData *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    UITextField* field = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(125,15, 170, 40)];
    field.delegate = self;
    field.tag = 1;

    field.text = self.contentOfTextField;
    [cell addSubView:field];
    [field release];
    return cell;
```

At last, apply this to update contentOfTextField everytime you edit it:

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField*)textField
{
    UITableViewCell* cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath(/*the indexPath of your cell*/)];
    UITextField* t = (UITextField*)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    self.contentOfTextField = t.text;
}
```

Comment: thanx for ur reply i am new to iphone, can u please give me some sample code to do that

Comment: @Ravi I don't have Xcode here so I typed all code in a text editor, it may contain some typos.

Answer (score 1):

Save the data when/while user is writing (set yourself as the delegate of the textfields) and in cellForRow check is there is data saved. If it is, load it. Otherwise set the placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

You had to save the data entered in a table cell, so that when you scroll the tableview , it does not lost.

Hope it helps.....

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem.. Then I found problem in

```
if (cell == nil) {
    //  cell = [[[CustomCellStudentData alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    cell = [[[CustomCellStudentData alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:nil] autorelease];
}
```

Use

```
switch(indexPath.section)
```

and whole code in curly braces...like

```
if (cell == nil) {
    //  cell = [[[CustomCellStudentData alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    cell = [[[CustomCellStudentData alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:nil] autorelease];


switch(indexPath.section) .........
.........
.......
 }

return cell;
}
```

Hope this will work

Answer (score -2):

First of all, because you **explicitly** tell it to lose it's data in two places:

> ```
> tfText[0] = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(125,15, 170, 40)]; // Number one
> cell.accessoryView = tfText[0];
> tfText[0].delegate = self;
> tfText[0].text = @""; // <== Set this to something useful, instead.
> ```

Then there is this:

> ```
> cell = [[[CustomCellStudentData alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:nil] autorelease];
> ```

If you want to reuse a cell, it needs that identifier!
As you seem to have at least two types of cells, those should be at least two distinct identifiers...

Next, you are setting yourself as the delegate of the text field — that's all fine and dandy, but do you implement the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol and store the data being input in `textFieldDidEndEditing:`?

There are several ways of solving this, but you should probably create one `NSMutableArray` per section to store the values from your input fields. (Which you should set up in your initializer.)

Oh and at the moment, you are leaking `UITextField`s all over the place...