# TextField return null when the cell is scrolled out of window

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableViewCell with 10 rows, inside they I have UITextFields.

When I try to get the value inside the textfield my code returns that value, but when I scroll down my table (put my textfield out of window) and I try to get the value inside him my code returns null!

```
NSIndexPath *myIP = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0];
        ProfileTableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:myIP];
        UITextView *text1 = (UITextView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
        UITextView *text2 = (UITextView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:2];
```

Why this is happening? **Because when the cell is scrolled out of window, the textfield may be released**

And what I can do to solve this problem? **Save the input in somewhere and read from there in cell construction method**

Well I get this answers reading this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6148657/data-in-the-text-field-is-set-to-null-when-i-scroll-the-table-view), now 4 years ago is passed, I believe that have a more modern solution to solve this problem, right?

Comment: Nope. That is still the way to go.

Comment: Correct. A cell is just a view into your data, it can't be used to store data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs, `UITableView` provides "a means for displaying and editing hierarchical lists of information."

It is not meant to act as a store for any data, it merely provides the user a way to interact with it.

As per the answer you linked to, you will have to store this data elsewhere if you want it to persist after the cell has been reused or released.